# C# EF Core code first FK in existing Table

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am adding a new entity/table to the DB, and is a one to one relationship to an existing table.

[Existing table] has one [New Table]. But since existing table contains records, the alter table fails for the new FK.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address? Adress{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<StudentClass> Classes { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street{ get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

What could be a good approach to face this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: *is a one to one* you either have to relax it to 1:0 and forget the existing, or you have to make the table, fill it with related data for every record that exists, then create the FK. Which is the 1:1 by the way? I see Address and Class but they seem like candidates for 1:M or M:M to me.. One address might ahve many students in it, and one student might have many addresses in their life. Same for classes

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess It could Be a 1:M. I just wrote a random example trying to show a simple model. You mention creating the table(address) and filling it with realted data, how Could You acheive this with migrations?